# How to hide EditItemTemplate controls while exporting Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

This is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" BorderColor="#ececec" BorderWidth="2px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#F6F6F6" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"  RowStyle-BackColor="white" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#F6F6F6" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" DataKeyNames="UsuarioId" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand" OnRowEditing="GridView1_OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting" Width="100%" CssClass="GridViewStyle" >
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div>
            No hay datos para mostrar :(
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tipo Usuario ID (Dato momentaneo)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("tipo") %>' runat="server">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTipoUsuarioId" Text='<%#Eval("tipo") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="tipoUsuario" DataValueField="tipoUsuarioId" DataSourceID="sqlDB" CssClass="ddl">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDB" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn%>" runat="server" SelectCommand="Select * from Tipo_Usuario"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("nombre") %>' runat="server">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" Text='<%#Eval("nombre") %>' runat="server" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombreFooter"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br/>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1" ControlToValidate="txtNombreFooter"
                    ErrorMessage="Requiere nombre!"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contraseña">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("contraseña") %>' runat="server"  >
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtContraseña" Text='<%#Eval("contraseña") %>' runat="server"  required="true" ></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtContraseñaFooter"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <br/>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1" ControlToValidate="txtContraseñaFooter"
                ErrorMessage="Requiere contraseña!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Habilitado">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="habilitado" Text='<%#Eval("habilitado") %>' runat="server">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtHabilitado" Text='<%#Eval("habilitado") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-warning" BackColor="#EC971F" Text="Editar" ForeColor="white" CommandName="Edit"  runat="server" ><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Borrar" CommandName="Delete"  runat="server" > <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Assets/ICONS/Save.png" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Update" Width="20" Height="20"  runat="server"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Assets/ICONS/Cancel.png" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20" Height="20"  runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Assets/ICONS/xls.png" OnClick="ExportDataToExcel"  Width="40" Height="40"  runat="server"/>
                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Agregar" CommandName="Agregar"  runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1"></asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the code to export:

```html
public void ExportDataToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
    GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = false;
    GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = false;

    Response.ClearContent();  //Clear any content
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=Usuarios.xls"); //Export as XLS (Excel)
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter); //Saves all the content including rows.

    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter); 
    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString()); //Gridview data is going to be converted for a xls file
    Response.End();
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Like I said on the title, I want to hide TextBox and buttons while exporting to excel in order to only see the data. Those controls are inside `EditItemTemplate` tags. On the aspx website the GridView show data from SQL server database, what I want to do is to export it as a table.

Comment: Just looking at your code, I can visualise controls in your footer. Is that what you want to hide?

Comment: No, I want to hide what is inside: <EditItemTemplate> </EditItemTemplate>